# Validity of the Riemann series theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-sum

A classic example of the Riemann series theorem use the alternating harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ that converges to $\ln(2)$ when $k \rightarrow \infty $ and rearrange it to $\sum_{n=1}^k (\frac{1}{2n - 1} - \frac{1}{4n - 2} - \frac{1}{4n})$ that converges to $\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)$ when $k \rightarrow \infty $

But if we strictly compare the terms for those two sum from n=1 to k with $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{4k} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ we found for k=1 :

\begin{array}{l|cccc} 
\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^4 \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} 
& 1 &  -\frac{1}{2} & +\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{4} \\ \hline 
\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^1 (\frac{1}{2n - 1} - \frac{1}{4n - 2} - \frac{1}{4n})  & 1 &  -\frac{1}{2} &  & -\frac{1}{4} \\ \hline
\small \text{Term not taken in account} & & & +\frac{1}{3}  \\ 
\small \text{in the rearranged series}
\end{array}

for k=2 :

\begin{array}{l|cccc} 
\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^8 \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} 
& 1 &  -\frac{1}{2} & +\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{4} & +\frac{1}{5}& -\frac{1}{6} &  +\frac{1}{7}& -\frac{1}{8} \\ \hline 
\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^2 (\frac{1}{2n - 1} - \frac{1}{4n - 2} - \frac{1}{4n})  & 1 &  -\frac{1}{2} & +\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{4} & & -\frac{1}{6} &  & -\frac{1}{8} \\ \hline
\small \text{Terms not taken in account} & & & & & +\frac{1}{5} & &  +\frac{1}{7}  \\
\small \text{in the rearranged series}
\end{array}

for k=3 :

\begin{array}{l|cccc} 
\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{12} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} 
& 1 -\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3} -\frac{1}{4} +\frac{1}{5} -\frac{1}{6} &  +\frac{1}{7} & -\frac{1}{8} & +\frac{1}{9} & -\frac{1}{10}&  +\frac{1}{11}& -\frac{1}{12} \\ \hline 
\sum_{1}^3 (\frac{1}{2n - 1} - \frac{1}{4n - 2} - \frac{1}{4n})  & 1 -\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3} -\frac{1}{4} +\frac{1}{5} -\frac{1}{6} &  & -\frac{1}{8} &  & -\frac{1}{10}& & -\frac{1}{12}  \\ \hline
\small \text{Terms not taken in account} & &  +\frac{1}{7} & & +\frac{1}{9} & & +\frac{1}{11} \\
\small \text{in the rearranged series}
\end{array}

And so on, with always a number of terms not taken in account in the rearranged series increasing with k, which are the inverses of odds numbers going from $\frac{1}{2k + 1}$ to $\frac{1}{4k-1}$ which is equal to $\sum_{p=k}^{2k-1}\frac{1}{2p+1}$ ([thanks to Carlo](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/412658/sum-of-changing-termes-serie)) which can be approximated by an integral over p equals to $\frac{1}{2}\ln(\frac{4k−1}{2k+1})$ that converges to $\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)$ when $k \rightarrow  \infty $

In short :

\begin{array}{lllll} 
\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^k (\frac{1}{2n - 1} - \frac{1}{4n - 2} - \frac{1}{4n}) & = & \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{4k} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} & - & \displaystyle \sum_{p=k}^{2k-1}\frac{1}{2p+1}
\\
\small \text{Rearranged series} & = & \small \text{original series} & - & \small \text{Terms not taken in account}
\\
\frac{1}{2}\ln(2) & = & \ln(2) & - & \frac{1}{2}\ln(2)
\end{array}

So the Riemann series theorem is false ?

Comment: Why do you claim that it is false? I see nothing in your post that supports that.

Comment: I do not claim, I'm asking

Comment: That's easy then: no it is not false. But what has the rest of what you wrote in your post to do with the question?

Comment: Something that's worth noting is that although in each partial sum you will find terms that appear to be missing, for any term in the sum there is some partial sum where it will be added, so all of the terms appear exactly once and the new infinite sum is a valid rearrangement of the original sum. So although your analysis here explains why the rearrangements converge to different values, it is still true that they converge to their respective different values.

Comment: Your wording is misleading. There is no term in $\sum\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ that is not taken into account in the rearrangement. It is just that some terms appear much later than the others in the rearrangement. In particular, even if $(b_n)$ is a rearrangement of $(a_n)$, it need **not** be the case that $(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ is a rearrangement of $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ for each $n$.

Comment: Yes, but you can see that for each missing terms "recovered" at the "lower side", there is two more added at the "upper side", which make the sum of missing terms increase. That increasing sum of missing terms is equal to $\sum_{p=k}^{2k-1}\frac{1}{2p+1}$ which tends toward $\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)$ when $k \mapsto \infty$

Comment: Write $a_n=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$, and let $\sigma:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be $$\sigma \quad:\quad(1,2,3,4,5,6,\ldots)\quad\leftrightarrow\quad(1,2,4,3,6,8,5,10,12,\ldots).$$ So $\sum_n a_{\sigma(n)}$ is precisely your rearrangement of $\sum_n a_n=\sum_n\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$. Then what you observed is that $$\{\sigma(n):n\leq3k\}=\{1,2,\ldots,4k\}\setminus\{2p+1:k\leq p<2k\} $$ and hence $$\sum_{n=1}^{3k}a_{\sigma(k)}=\sum_{n=1}^{4k}a_n-\sum_{p=k}^{2k-1}a_{2p+1}.$$ However, this has *nothing to do with* the fact that $\sum_n a_{\sigma(n)}$ is a rearrangement of $\sum_n a_n$.

Comment: Your series $\sum_n a_{\sigma(n)}=a_1+a_2+a_4+a_3+a_6+a_8+a_5+a_{10}+a_{12}+\cdots $ is a rearrangement of $\sum_n a_n$ merely because $\sigma$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ itself. I suspect that you are puzzled because the set $\{\sigma(1),\ldots,\sigma(k)\}$ becomes "sparse" as $k$ grows (in the sense that it is missing $25\%$ of the terms in the set $\{1,2,\ldots,4k-1,4k\}$). But again, this is not a problem. A function $\tau:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ can be a bijection even if $\{\tau(1),\tau(2),\ldots,\tau(k)\}$ become "sparse" as $k\to\infty$.

Comment: The fact that there is a bijection between the two sets has *nothing to do* with the fact that for any k there are some terms excluded in the rearranged series sum, even when $k \to  \infty$. From my point of view this is a problem because, in a way, it's calling into question the commutativity of addition.

Comment: That is precisely why the ordinary definition for infinite series should not be considered as a true summation. On the other hand, there is another, more strict notion of infinite series in which the value of a series is not altered by permuting the order of terms. For the series in a finite-dimensional Banach space (such as $\mathbb{R}^d$ or $\mathbb{C}^d$), it can be proved that this coincides with the notion of absolute convergence. (I.e., a series in a finite-dimensional Banach space converges to the same value under rearrangement if and only if it converges absolutely.)